# why lxc command gives me permission denied error?

Tags: permissions, debian, lxc

I have some problem in executing command lxc. when i try without sudo i get the error:

```
$ lxc storage list
Error: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/unix.socket: connect: permission denied
```

when i try with sudo i get:

```
$ sudo lxc storage list
sudo: lxc: command not found
```

i don't understand the problem about permission and i cannot solve this type of issue. Any suggestion is appreciated

INFO: i'm runnign Debian 10 buster on a virtual machine, i installed lxd and lxc by:

```
$ sudo snap install lxd
$ sudo apt install lxc
```

modified PATH with:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/snap/bin/lxc:/snap/bin/lxd
```

i added my account to sudoers:

```
moro ALL=(ALL)ALL
```

if i run

```
$ su-
root@debian:~# lxc storage list
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+---------+
|  NAME   | DESCRIPTION | DRIVER |                   SOURCE                   | USED BY |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+---------+
| default |             | btrfs  | /var/snap/lxd/common/lxd/disks/default.img | 14      |
+---------+-------------+--------+--------------------------------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as my understanding goes, lxc uses the `lxc` group, in which your `$USER` has to be.  Thus everything should work as expected if you add your user to the lxc group, e.g. via

```
sudo adduser $USER lxd
```

This is mentioned without an example on the lxd page [getting started](https://linuxcontainers.org/lxd/getting-started-cli/)  under *access control* and with an example in this 
  nice [tutorial for Ubuntu 16.04](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-setting-up-lxd-1604#2-install-lxd), which should be applicable to many other debian based OS.